# How to ignore hostname verification or setup verifier in AXIS2 client

Tags: ssl, wso2, apache-axis, hostname, httpconnection

We have a spring-boot based web application and using WSO2 CEP framework. How can we ignore the hostname verification or setup customized hostname verifier for AXIS2 client?

We can do this for Java HttpsURLConnection

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new WildcardHostnameVerifier());
```

Or this way for apache HttpClient

```
    // setup a WildcardHostNameVerifier for support verifying the hostname of wildcard certificate
    sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new WildcardHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

But don't know how to do for AXIS2 client, we have found a way to setup customized trustManger only.

```
final SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslCtx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new CustomX509TrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());

stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER, new Protocol("https",
            (ProtocolSocketFactory) new SSLProtocolSocketFactory(sslCtx), 443));
```

Comment: Will this help? http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel/1.4/org/apache/axis2/transport/nhttp/HttpCoreNIOSSLSender.java

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ycr. This might be useful if I can extend it and customzied the verify(). However, the wso2-cep-client 1.0.10 which we have used is dependency with axis2-kernel 1.6.4. It seems that there is no HttpCoreNIOSSLSender anymore?

Comment: And how could I do to set the SSLIOSessionHandler after I got it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TrustAllTrustManager](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/java/security/TrustAllTrustManager.html)

```
SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("http");
sslCtx.init(null, new TrustManager[] {new TrustAllTrustManager()}, null);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER, 
          new Protocol("https",(ProtocolSocketFactory)new SSLProtocolSocketFactory(sslCtx),443));
```

See [this blog post](https://asitha.github.io/cs/programming/gotchas/wso2/2015/02/25/ignore-trust-store-when-connecting-to-wso2-server/).

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, thanks for your answer. I have done that in our development project. For production, however, we need to verify the server certificate for security reason. But there may have sometimes the case is the hostname is not matched or we need to match the wildcard certificate.

Comment: why can't you create certs with wild card?

Comment: We probably would have the certificate(two.abc.com), but the hostname is not matched (e.g., connect from localhost), or the wildcard certificate(*.two.abc.com) but connect from one.two.abc.com and/or two.abc.com.

Comment: So, we have to let user to set the hostname verification properly or customized the hostname verifier, because I think the default verifier of axis2 will not pass the *.two.abc.com and two.abc.com case.

Comment: You can set Subject Alternative Names (SAN) for your cert to match all possible hostnames..

Comment: Search for SAN in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, sorry for the late reply. Although SAN can list all possible hostname, it will not work if we have to apply a non-UCC public CA certificate.

Comment: And I realized one thing wired, that is the TrustAllTrustManager would not affect the hostname verification of certificate, isn't it? And I also found that whatever I have customized the TrustManager or not, The axis2 seems not verify the hostname anyway. Any kind of hostname with any certificate is valided.